# Shift-tab issue

Tags: vb6, tab-ordering

I am new to VB but working on a VB project now.
I ran into a strange problem about Shift-Tab.

The tabbing order is correct where it will go through all the textboxes, checkboxes, etc to the Accept and Cancel button at the end of the form, then cycle back to the beginning of the form.

However, if you Shift-Tab, it will skip the Accept and Cancel button. It works correctly for all other controls though.

The Tab Indices seem correct to me.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the cause? I'm at my wits end so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are footer buttons part of a custom `UserControl`?

Comment: Yes, the Accept and Cancel button is a custom UserControl. Basically, the control is a footer that consists of an Accept and a Cancel button.

Comment: This is a by-design behaviour. On Tab or Shift-Tab the first constituent control of the `UserControl` gets focused. You can check for `Shift` being pressed and focus last one manually.

Answer (score 1):

Check for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on `EnterFocus` event of the `UserControl` like this

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal VKey As Long) As Integer

Public Function IsKeyPressed(ByVal lVirtKey As KeyCodeConstants) As Boolean
    IsKeyPressed = ((GetAsyncKeyState(lVirtKey) And &H8000) = &H8000)
End Function

Private Sub UserControl_EnterFocus()
    If IsKeyPressed(vbKeyTab) And IsKeyPressed(vbKeyShift) Then
        cmdCancel.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is very informative and makes sense to me, however, the code still refuses to work. The EnterFocus() only fire when I Tab through the control but never get triggered when I Shift+Tab.

Comment: Is your "footer" `UserControl` nested in another `UserControl` on the form? Implement its `EnterFocus` event too.